# upload file to blobstore data store

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload, blobstore

I'm pretty new on Google app engine. so gyus please help me with this problem. definitively, my code is wrong but i can't where it is? here code:

```
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import datetime
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp \
    import template


class MyUsers(db.Model):
    firstname = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    lastname = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    email = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    zipcode = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    file = db.BlobProperty(
                    required=False)
    idea = db.TextProperty(
                    )
    ask = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    contact_back = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    phone = db.StringProperty(
                    required=False)
    regdate = db.DateTimeProperty(
                    auto_now_add=True)

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(
            template.render('expert.html',[]))


class Register(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
            self.response.out.write(
            template.render('expert.html',[]))

    def post(self):
        user = MyUsers(
            firstname = self.request.get('firstname'),
            lastname = self.request.get('lastname'),
            email = self.request.get('email'),
            zipcode = self.request.get('zipcode'),
            ask = self.request.get('ask'),
            idea = self.request.get('idea'),
            file = self.request.get('file'),
            contact_back = self.request.get('contact_back'),
            phone = self.request.get('phone'),
            )
        phone = self.request.get('phone')
        firstname = self.request.get('firstname')
        email = self.request.get('email')
        lastname = self.request.get('lastname')
        user.put()

        emailto = self.request.get('email')
        body = """Dear """+firstname+""":

        Thank you for registering.

        Please let us know if you have any questions.

        As One Source.
        """
        mail.send_mail("daniyar.seisenov@gmail.com", emailto, "Confirmation Email", body)
        mail.send_mail(sender="Daniyar Seisenov <daniyar.seisenov@gmail.com>",
              to="Daniyar Seisenov <daniyar.seisenov@gmail.com>",
              subject="New User",
              body="""
        This applicant has just registered. Please review:

        Firstname: """+firstname+"""
        Lastname: """+lastname+"""
        Email: """+email+"""
        Phone: """+phone+"""



        """)
        self.redirect('/')



class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')  # 'file' is file upload field in the form
        blob_info = upload_files[0]

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, resource):
        resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
        self.send_blob(blob_info)        
        self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())

class Users(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        myusers=db.GqlQuery(
            'SELECT * FROM MyUsers '
            'ORDER BY regdate DESC'
            )
        values = {
            'myusers':myusers,
            'totalmyusers' : myusers.count()
        }

        self.response.out.write(
            template.render('userscountandremove.html',
                            values))

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),
                                        ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                                        ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
                                          ('/register',Register),
                                          ('/userscountandremove',Users)],
                                         debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i press submit from expert.html, "file" doesn't go to the blobstore in data store. please help me, if you know what is a solution. thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit confusing, but the datastore and blobstore are two separate storage mechanisms in app engine.  The BlobProperty stores a blob in the datastore, not in the blobstore.

It looks like you're code would put a file into the BlobStore, but your MyUsers.file property needs to store the BlobStore key.

The other option is to actually store the blob in the datastore, in which case you wouldn't use BlobstoreUploadHandler, but rather you'd have to pull the object out of the POST data yourself, and store it in the MyUsers.file field.

Comment: thanks for your respons. don't you think my problem could be also here: self.redirect('/serve/%s' % blob_info.key())   in my template page action is: (/register).. i tried to replace %s with /register, but it doesn't work.. would you mind tell me what should i do with &s?thanks again

Comment: So do you want to store your file in the Blobstore or as a blob in the Datastore?  First and foremost, you need to figure that out.  Youre Register() function saves the file in the datastore, but the ServeHandler() tries to retrieve it from the Blobstore.

Comment: i want to store my file in the Blobstore. will be appreciate if you can help me with that

Comment: What have you tried after reading my initial answer?  The best direction I can give you is to make sure your UploadHandler() is hit so that the file is uploaded, then make sure you save the blob_info somewher (most likely in MyUsers.file).  Then when you want to fetch the file, make sure you use the same blob_info.